# Формировать CSV из массива php по команде от ajax и сразу отдаватьклиенту без сохранения на сервере

Tags: php, массивы, ajax, csv

Пытаюсь выгрузить массив, который я формирую с помощью php в csv для отдачи клиенту.
На стороне клиента ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',                        
        url: 'http://10.144.247.37/evaluation/q.php',
        data: { 'month':"1",'year':'2020' },    
        response: 'text',
        async:false,                   
        success:function (data) { 
            document.location.href="evaluation/q.php";
        }
    });
```

При запуске получаю csv файл с 1 строкой - элементом массива [0]. 
Хотя, если вместо

```
document.location.href="evaluation/q.php";
```

использовать

```
console.log(data);
```

то вижу в консоли все данные из массива.

Что делаю не так? Help...

Код php для формирования csv

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=br.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$outstream = fopen("php://output", "wb");    
foreach($array_resault as $item)
{
  fputcsv($outstream, $item, ';');
}

fclose($outstream);
```

---

Состав массива

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Поле 1
            [1] => Поле 2
            [2] => Поле 3
            [3] => Поле 4
            [4] => Поле 5
            [5] => Поле 6 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 992545469012020-1-31 12:39:17
            [1] => 97546546456901
            [2] => Разворот
            [3] => контроль
            [4] => оценка
            [5] => обработка

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23469012020-1-31 12:39:17
            [1] => 23412341432
            [2] => Разворот
            [3] => контроль
            [4] => оценка
            [5] => обработка

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function exportToCsv(filename, rows) {
    var processRow = function (row) {
        var finalVal = row['id'] + ',' + row['title'] + ',' +  row['total']; 
        return finalVal + '\n';
    };

var csvFile = 'Id' + ',' + 'Name' + ',' +  'Total' + '\n'; //первая строка
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
}
var blob = new Blob([csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
} else {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", filename);
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

}

Вызов:

```
exportToCsv('Dinners_' + name + '.csv', originalDataSet)
```

Comment: Массив сформирован в php, он не кодирован в json.

Comment: Вопрос в том,что ajax получает в ответ все строки, но, видимо, последовательно, по одной и сохраняет мне файл только с первой строкой

Comment: @Константин изменил ответ. У вас тут двойная иерархия. Попробуйте

Comment: Так отдает пустой csv.
Думаю что-то не так с ajax... Не могу разобраться - что именно.

Comment: @Константин  у вас такой код как у меня? (изменил еще раз :) )

Comment: да, внутрь предыдущего перебора вставил.

Comment: @Константин а ну да... я не увидел... у вас ну двойная структура)) Удалите вложенный цыкл

Comment: @Константин попробуйте не перебирать массив а сразу кинуть целеком

Comment: тогда возвращает "Array" в первую ячейку csv  и все.

Comment: Если вместо location.href="evaluation/q.php"; в ajax выполнить console.log(data); то получаю то что нужно. Вставляю через блокнот в csv и получается абсолютно правильная таблица результатов.
Вместо  location.href="evaluation/q.php"; надо юзать что-то другое?

Comment: @Константин попробуйте оформить экспорт как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: @Константин ужас, простите недосмотрел data  - это и есть ваш массив. А  location.href="evaluation/q.php"; вам вообще не нужно. Присвойте дата любой переменной и киньте её в экспорт. Стыдно то как(

Comment: @Александр Как кинуть в экспорт? Похоже, у меня есть пробел в знаниях, из-за которого у самого мозг не дошел до решения(

Comment: @Константин привел пример своего экспорта

Comment: @Александр, спасибо большое, выгрузка получилась! 
Осталось решить проблему кодировки)

Comment: @Константин а что с кодировкой?

Comment: @Александр, кракозябры в csv, при открытии через excel.
Приходится экспортировать "из текста" в экселе. автоматически определяет кодировку utf-8 (она в mysql у меня задана по умолчанию и в apache). 
mb_convert_encoding($resault_data, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251"); возвращает только кракозябры другого типа, не подающиеся перекодировке(

Comment: @Константин попробуйте вместо new Blob([csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }) вставить new Blob(["\ufeff"+csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })

Comment: @Александр, да, это решило проблему. Спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @Константин отлично, можете закрывать вопрос :)